# How to code a "try again" in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

I will try to describe my problem as the best I can. I have a method who (1)get all Grafana datasources via the API (2)create 2 JSON (3)post them to Grafana API.

The thing is sometimes one of my JSON is not finish when the code make the 3rd step so I got an error and the result is not what I want.

```js
updateDashboard = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
    console.log("called updateDashboard()");
    new Promise(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(resolve) {
        // get all the datasources of Grafana
        HTTP.call("GET", 'http://localhost:3000/api/datasources', {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': APIKEY,
                },
            },
            function(error, result) {
                if (!error) {
                    allDataSources = result.data;
                    resolve(allDataSources);
                } else {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });

    })).then(function(allDataSources) {
        // create the dashboard
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        //ANCHOR 
            var dataJSON = {
                //create the dashboard
                "annotations": {
                    "list": []
                },
                "description": "Containers metrics",
                "editable": true,
                "gnetId": null,
                "graphTooltip": 1,
                "hideControls": false,
                "id": null,
                "links": [],
                "refresh": "1s",
                //create the lines
                "rows": _.map(allDataSources, function(ds, index) {
                    return newGraphOverview(ds, index);
                }),
                //dashboard things
                "schemaVersion": 14,
                "style": "dark",
                "tags": [
                    "docker"
                ],
                "time": {
                    "from": "now-15m",
                    "to": "now"
                },
                "timepicker": {
                    "refresh_intervals": [
                        "1s",
                        "5s",
                        "10s",
                        "30s",
                        "1m",
                        "5m",
                        "15m",
                        "30m",
                        "1h",
                        "2h",
                        "1d"
                    ],
                    "time_options": [
                        "5m",
                        "15m",
                        "1h",
                        "6h",
                        "12h",
                        "24h",
                        "2d",
                        "7d",
                        "30d"
                    ]
                },
                "timezone": "browser",
                "title": "Docker Containers _custom_from_js",
                "version": 1
            }

            dataJSONDetails = newGraphDetails(allDataSources);

            resolve(dataJSON);

        });

    }).then(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(dataJSON) {
        // send the dashboard
        HTTP.call("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db", {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': APIKEY,
                },
                data: {
                    dashboard: dataJSON,
                    overwrite: true
                }
            },
            function(error, result) {
                if (!error) {
                    console.log("result post " + dataJSON.title + " ----------------------------------")
                    console.log(result);
                } else {
                   //HERE I WANT TO DO IF ERROR GO TO ANCHOR
                    console.log("error post " + dataJSON.title + "  ----------------------------------")
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });

        //send the dashboard for details view
        HTTP.call("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db", {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': APIKEY,
                },
                data: {
                    dashboard: dataJSONDetails,
                    overwrite: true
                }
            },
            function(error, result) {
                if (!error) {
                    console.log("result post " + dataJSONDetails.title + " ----------------------------------")
                    console.log(result);
                } else {
                //HERE I WANT TO DO IF ERROR GO TO ANCHOR
                    console.log("error post " + dataJSONDetails.title + " ----------------------------------")
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });

    }));
});
```

I know the code snipped doesn't work but it was easier for me to make it readable.

So someone could help me to make a thing like "if error try to create again" ? I have seen Meteor retries but it don't think it's what I need

Comment: Or is it my 2 posts who generate sometimes a problem ? Should I do one then the other one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use promises or callbacks. Write normal, synchronous-looking code as you've seen in Meteor examples.

```
var datasources = null;
try {
    var request1 = HTTP.call("GET", 'http://localhost:3000/api/datasources', {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': APIKEY,
                }
            });
    // From http://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call
    datasources = request.data;
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return;
}
// Do all the other steps you keep wanting to do...
```

Repeat a similar statement for your other HTTP calls. Generally, you will not be throwing errors unless `localhost` is unreachable, in which case everything is unreachable. So don't bother with try-catch. Let the exception be thrown and handled by the client (the caller of the method).

You shouldn't generally have to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment`.

Comment: Thank you for the help I'll try to make my method again without Promises. I don't know why I need to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` but I always have an error like `Your code must run in a Fiber`

Comment: It does respect the order of the calls, it's synchronous. So the first `HTTP.call` will happen, and then the second `HTTP.call` will happen. That's a feature Meteor provides. Otherwise, you're getting issues with "Your code must run in a fiber" because it should be inside a method, a `Meteor.startup` or in a `Meteor.publish`. This should be written in the server, not the client. Try using methods. Suffice it to say, the answer is correct but there's a lot for you to learn about the platform!